# Download one thread of text

Tags: sms

How do I select one string of text messages and download to PC so that I can print?  I've tried downloading and it provides a .hbk file which I can not open.  I don't even know where to look on my HTC to look for my SMS card file information to convert to something else.

Answer (score 0):

.hbk is HTC messages backup extension: you can "write" them only via backup from phone and "read" only via the restore option. 
See  [this](http://file.org/extension/hbk#) for more information about how to open or write these files

Answer (score 0):

There are many apps that can backup your SMSes to your email account or to an XML file. The one I use, called SMS Backup+, would upload your SMSes to your gmail account under an SMS label, which can then be printed from your mailbox. There are probably apps than can export to text file as well.

edit: or in fact, there are apps that can print your message via Google Cloud Print, e.g. Cloud Print by Paulo Fernandes or Printer Share by Mobile Dynamix.

Comment: Ok, I have the SMS Backup+ app.  When I back up and ask for it to be sent to my google account it sends it in a .hbk file.  What do you mean by it going to my account under an SMS label?